# how to download file on website behind oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, python-requests

I'm trying to access a file on a site that I want to pull every day as it updates.

https://www.website.com/path/file.json

If I go through the UI, I enter my username and password to the oath system which then lets me through.

Trying to use python to emulate that:

using client_id /secret I get back a bearer token: abcdxyz

headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer abcdxyz'}

```
requests.get('https://www.website.com/path/file.json',headers = headers)

cookie= {'Cookie': 'abcdxyz'} 
requests.post('https://www.website.com/path/file.json, cookies=cookies)
```

Im pretty sure im doing it the wrong way but I don't know how to look up this problem.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: nope, I just put this on the backburner

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it outputs `{'Authorization':'Bearer abcdxyz'}`, but rather `{'Cookie': 'abcdxyz'}`. I guess that could be a first step